# Connect code to using statement with Roslyn

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Is there anyway to connect a piece of code to its "using" statement using the Roslyn framework?

For example, given this piece of code:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Serilog;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CodeAnalyzer.Service.CodeAnalysis.CSharp
{
public static class CSharpCodeAnalyser
{

/// <summary>
/// Retrieves all of the using statements from a code page
/// </summary>
/// <param name="codeDocument"></param>
/// <param name="logger"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static List<string> IdentifyUsings(string codeDocument, ILogger logger)
{
    var usingList = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(codeDocument);
        CompilationUnitSyntax root = tree.GetCompilationUnitRoot();
        foreach (var item in root.Usings)
        {
            usingList.Add(item.Name.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex, ex.Message);
        throw;
    }

    return usingList;
}
```

}
}

Could I know what assembly "CSharpSyntaxTree" belongs to?

Comment: If you had this information, what would you then do with it? I ask because there's some fun cases around extension methods and such you have to think about, and depending on your goal you may need to do different things.

Comment: So essentially I’m trying to create a tool that will analyze commits to a git repo and identify which libraries were used in the code update so I can connect it to a developer.  That way I can track a developers skills

Comment: What exactly do you want? Know the namespace or the assembly of a type? Your previous comment does not match the question.

Comment: Paulo, have a look at the example I posted.  I would like to know both the namespace and the assembly.  But if I had to choose one it would be the assembly.  I figured if I could find out the namespace I could use the code I already have to identify the assembly.  But a simple piece of code that could do both at once would be optimal.

Comment: So do you actually need to connect the types to usings, or is your real question "you just want to know what namespaces the types are from?" For example, does your hypothetical tool consider "Foo" and "Fully.Qualified.Foo" to both be a use of "Fully.Qualified"?

Comment: I just really need to know what namespace and hence assembly the type is from

Comment: Ah, that's much easier! And if you just care about the assembly then you can skip the namespace entirely since a namespace could have things from multiple assemblies at once. You may want to rephrase you question and then we can answer.

Comment: Ok I changed it

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out how to do this.

First I needed to build a workspace containing my entire solution.  I did this through the Buildalyzer tool

```
        public static Tuple<AdhocWorkspace, IEnumerable<Project>> GetWorkspace(string solutionFilePath, ILogger logger)
    {
        Tuple<AdhocWorkspace, IEnumerable<Project>> results;
        var projectList = new List<Project>();
        AdhocWorkspace workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();


        try
        {
            AnalyzerManager manager = new AnalyzerManager(solutionFilePath);
            foreach (var project in manager.Projects)
            {
                projectList.Add(project.Value.AddToWorkspace(workspace));
            }
            results = new Tuple<AdhocWorkspace, IEnumerable<Project>>(workspace, projectList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex, ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Once I had a workspace all I needed to do was the following:

```
var workspace = GetWorkspace(solutionName, _logger);


                foreach (var project in workspace.Item1.CurrentSolution.Projects)
                {
                    foreach (var document in project.Documents)
                    {
                        _logger.Information("");
                        _logger.Information(project.Name + "\t\t\t" + document.Name);
                        var semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync();
                        var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync();

                        foreach (var item in root.DescendantNodes())
                        {
                            var typeInfo = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(item);
                            if (typeInfo.Type != null)
                            {
                                _logger.Information(String.Format("Node: {0}", item.ToString()));
                                _logger.Information(String.Format("Type:{0}", typeInfo.Type.Name.ToString()));
                                _logger.Information(String.Format("ContainingAssembly:{0}", typeInfo.Type.ContainingAssembly));
                                _logger.Information(String.Format("ContainingNamespace:{0}", typeInfo.Type.ContainingNamespace));
                            }

                        }

                        
                    }
                }
```